# Why this loop doesn't work correctly? Python, Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, loops, xlrd

So I'm building an Django API, and I'm trying to put a bunch of information through Selenium, I have a JSON file that I converted to an Excell file and using `xlrd`, i read it and I want to put the data in Django like this :

```
for curr_row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    titlevalue = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 0)
    descriptionvalue = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 2)
    imagevalue = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1)
    keywordsvalue = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 3)

    title.send_keys(titlevalue)
    description.send_keys(descriptionvalue)
    image.clear()
    image.send_keys(imagevalue)
    keywords.send_keys(keywordsvalue)
    save.click()
    addarticle.click()
```

This loop in my mind should do it, like post an article after article with the data from the Excell file, but it only works once, it writes the first article with the first row and then it stops, it doesn't run again, why?

Comment: So what is the value of sheet.nrows ?

Comment: workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(pathexcell)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)